# Charging problem

Tags: ipod

Can i use Samsung tab 8.9 adapter for charging ipod 5. Will it damage my iPod.I never tried charging my iPod using tabs adapter. I need help. U wont get a adapter for ipod 5 while buying it

Comment: Maybe add some clarity to this.  Are you referencing the USB adapter, the box that plugs into the wall and the USB cable plugs into the box?

Answer (score 1):

A standard USB port provides +5v , which is what the iPod uses, so you should be ok, assuming the adapter mimics the power of a USB port, which it should, if it has a Female USB on it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the volts on the adapter and on the iPod. If the adapter works with a higher voltage than the iPod, it will damage it. But I suppose they both use around 5v so that should be okay. Don't worry about the amps tho, your iPod will take what it needs and leave the rest.